# VS 2015 Macro Explanation

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015

We found this macro

```
#define OFFSETOFCLASS(base, derived) \
    ((DWORD)(DWORD_PTR)(STATIC_CAST(base*)((derived*)8))-8)
```

while working on some Windows Kits header which resides here

`c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\Shlwapi.h`

What does this macro actually do ?

Comment: Do you just want to know what it does, or do you want each part explained?

Comment: Each part explained. If possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This macro calculates offset between the base and derived pointers.

First it takes a random address (`8`) and casts it to `derived*`. Basically it says "let's say that some random Derived starts at memory address 8".

Then it static_casts it to `base*`. Since `base` is the base class of `derived`, the resulting `base*` pointer will or will not point at the same point in memory (`8`), depending on it's layout.

Then it casts the result to `DWORD_PTR` and then to `DWORD` to make a number out of the pointer. Finally it subtracts 8 (the initial value it used) and gets the offset. Any random number can be used instead of `8`.

For example if both `base` and `derived` are empty classes, then:

- derived * will point to 8
- base* will point to 8
- the result DWORD will be 8
- 8-8 = 0, so the offset between the pointers is 0.

Comment: Is suspect that `8` is the size of a pointer, for cases where the runtime tacks on bookkeeping data *before* allocated objects, which may cause an underflow inside `STATIC_CAST` otherwise (offsetting past zero into the negatives). It's only a hunch, though.

Comment: @Quentin, yup, that is a reasonable assumption.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Under what conditions, will the result not be zero ? If it is always zero, then what is the purpose of the casts here ?

Comment: @Recker, for example `struct A{ int something; }` struct B : public A {};`

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall We just tried this and the value was Zero. I actually wanted to know if at all it would become non zero. If yes, then under what conditions ? Again if it is always zero, then what is the purpose of the macro ?

Comment: @Recker, Ok, the exact memory layout is implementation-defined, but here you go: http://ideone.com/Qbkcfc (`A * b = new B();` is not neccessary of course, I forgot to remove it.)

Comment: @Recker: The offset is non-zero for multiple inheritance scenarios with classes that have virtual functions (when compiled with Visual Studio). The specific use case for this macro is in manually chaining COM interfaces.

Comment: @Quentin: That's hardly conclusive. There is no *"offsetting past zero into the negatives"*. `DWORD` is unsigned, and unsigned underflow is well defined in C. Besides, even **if** the runtime tacks bookkeeping data before allocated objects (which it does), that has no bearing on the pointer arithmetic used in this macro.